# when assigning value to a copy of dataframe, the original is also changed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I provide a simplified example regarding my question:

I have a data frame like this:

```
cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand','Price'], index=['Car_1','Car_2','Car_3','Car_4'])
```

if I print it it looks like this:

```
print (df)
            Brand  Price
Car_1     Honda Civic  22000
Car_2  Toyota Corolla  25000
Car_3      Ford Focus  27000
Car_4         Audi A4  35000
```

Now i want to create a copy of it and make only the first row of the copy eqaul to zero as this:

```
copy_df=df

copy_df.iloc[0]=0
```

my expectation is that only the first row of the copy, `copy_df` would be changed like this:

```
print (copy_df)
                Brand  Price
Car_1               0      0
Car_2  Toyota Corolla  25000
Car_3      Ford Focus  27000
Car_4         Audi A4  35000
```

but when I print the `df` now, its first row is also affected:

```
print (df)

              Brand  Price
Car_1               0      0
Car_2  Toyota Corolla  25000
Car_3      Ford Focus  27000
Car_4         Audi A4  35000
```

My expectation was that the first row in `df` should not be changed.

would anyone please clarify?

Comment: `copy_df=df` That does _not_ create a copy of df.  It makes a new _name_ copy_df that refers to the _same_ object.

Comment: `df.copy()` is how you actually make a copy

Comment: @JohnGordon Is this only in Python? as far as I remember in Matlab this made a copy, I am so confused...

Comment: In some languages `a=b` will make a copy of b.  But not python.

Comment: I learned Python from scratch myself, I never encountered this. Nowhere they talked about this important thing in all the videos I watched! what is the logic behind this?  @JohnGordon

Comment: More precisely, for many objects, `a=b` only copies the address of the object while retaining the underlying data. This is not true for primitive datatype, e.g. `int` or `float`. For example `a=5; b=a; b=4` doesn't change `a`.

Comment: @Sean you haven't encountered it doesn't mean it's not there. Maybe you didn't learn pointer just yet. Most Python objects are pointer only.

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @QuangHoang any resource you would suggest for that?

Comment: @QuangHoang Also , I appreciate if you explain more the example you provided. Why in this case ```a``` is not changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you make copy like this

```
df_copy=df.copy()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In python, the default of certain data types is to assign copies by reference. In python, this is known as [mutability](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python/). I would familiarize yourself with this idea because it shows up in the implementation of lists as well. It is very similar (but not the same) as the idea of ["Pass by reference" or "Pass by value"](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference)- perhaps you are more familiar with those terms.

In Matlab, everything is passed by value. So if you have a list, then all the *values* are copied. Whereas in this case of a python dataframe, the *memory address* of the variable is copied/assigned.

In order to fix this, you should use the **df.copy()** method in order to actually duplicate the data frame at its *current state.*

There are good/helpful uses for mutability and pass-by-reference, but it can be confusing when coming from other languages.

```
copy_df = df.copy()
```